# Getting wrapper to push footer down

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting the elements in my `<div id="wrapper">` to push down my footer. At the moment the wrapper flows into the footer. How can I fix that?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="findcontent">
    <div id="criteriabar">
    </div>
    <div id="searchresults">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height:65px;
}

#wrapper {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

#findcontent {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 960px;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

#criteriabar {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
}

#searchresults {
    position: relative;
    width: 770px;
    left: 40px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 30px;
}

#footer {
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: solid 1px #CCD9FF;
    margin: 20px 0px 10px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Adding `class="clearfix"` alone didn't do it. I had to also change `top` to `margin-top` for floating elements inside of `<div id="find content">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have floated divs inside your wrapper which need to be cleared. You have two options:

Option 1:

```
#wrapper {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden; /* This guy */
}
```

Option 2:

// CSS

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

// HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="findcontent">
    <div id="criteriabar">
    </div>
    <div id="searchresults">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The only way I can seem to push things down is by using the `min-height`.

Comment: Adding `class="clearfix"` worked after changing `top` to `margin-top`.